# Enterprise iOS: will adding an existing bundle ID to an app group invalidate already deployed apps?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, enterprise

I have a mission critical enterprise app deployed to the field. I want to add its bundle ID to an app group. I understand that the already-deployed app won't be recognized as belonging to a group until I update their provisioning profile. I'd like to confirm that by simply adding the already-deployed app's bundle ID to an App Group in the developer portal, that action won't invalidate the provisioning profile of my existing apps in the field with that bundle ID, or otherwise cause the already deployed app to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile is embedded in the app bundle. Devices do not automatically update the embedded provisioning profile when it is updated. You either need to install an updated version of the app or distribute an updated provisioning profile using an MDM solution in order to affect any change on the device.

This means that simply updating the provisioning profile on the developer portal will not have any affect the installed apps in any way.

Comment: per my original post: "I understand that the already-deployed app won't be recognized as belonging to a group until I update their provisioning profile". That wasn't my question - my question was does adding a bundle ID to a group invalidate existing instances of the app in the field - I think I'll need to contact developer support for an answer.

Comment: No, it won't because, as I said in my answer, the devices don't automatically pull the updated provisioning profile - So any changes you make won't affect installed apps.